# Rails 6 blank page when running server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, ruby-on-rails-6

I moved to rails 6 after being developing in rails 5 and I'm getting a misterious error when running rails server. When I go to localhost://3000 the browser shows a blank page and nothing else. Did anybody have the same problem?
Important: This blank page started to show after I installed bootstrap with yarn. 
PD: I'm using foreman tu run puma and compile webpacker, but happens the same with rails s command

here are the logs from the server:

```
10:07:50 web.1       | started with pid 11365
10:07:50 webpacker.1 | started with pid 11366
10:07:52 web.1       | Puma starting in single mode...
10:07:52 web.1       | * Version 4.3.1 (ruby 2.7.0-p0), codename: Mysterious Traveller
10:07:52 web.1       | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
10:07:52 web.1       | * Environment: development
10:07:57 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3035/
10:07:57 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /packs/
10:07:57 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /home/enzo/Ruby/Rails/Aguara/aguara/public/packs
10:07:57 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
10:08:06 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:06 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
10:08:07 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/type.rb:27: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:07 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/type/adapter_specific_registry.rb:9: warning: The called method `add_modifier' is defined here
10:08:08 web.1       | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:5000
10:08:08 web.1       | Use Ctrl-C to stop
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wdm｣: Hash: c16cbbe009c350199791
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | Version: webpack 4.41.5
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | Time: 18836ms
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | Built at: 05/04/2020 10:08:16 AM
10:08:16 webpacker.1 |                                           Asset       Size            Chunks                         Chunk Names
10:08:16 webpacker.1 |          js/application-64644ee2e024eff1d7f7.js   1.72 MiB       application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
10:08:16 webpacker.1 |      js/application-64644ee2e024eff1d7f7.js.map   1.89 MiB       application  [emitted] [dev]        application
10:08:16 webpacker.1 |     js/bootstrap_custom-4a75b3f7b43b52ae2490.js    929 KiB  bootstrap_custom  [emitted] [immutable]  bootstrap_custom
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | js/bootstrap_custom-4a75b3f7b43b52ae2490.js.map   1.04 MiB  bootstrap_custom  [emitted] [dev]        bootstrap_custom
10:08:16 webpacker.1 |                                   manifest.json  738 bytes                    [emitted]              
10:08:16 webpacker.1 | ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.1/lib/active_model/type/integer.rb:13: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.1/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/oid/specialized_string.rb:12: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.1/lib/active_model/type/value.rb:8: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:28: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:6: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.2.1/lib/action_view/unbound_template.rb:24: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionview-6.0.2.1/lib/action_view/template.rb:130: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activemodel-6.0.2.1/lib/active_model/translation.rb:67: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/i18n-1.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:179: warning: The called method `translate' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:67: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:313: warning: The called method `form_authenticity_token' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/collection_cache_association_loading.rb:7: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/collection_cache_association_loading.rb:12: warning: The called method `relation_from_options' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:119: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-4.0.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:78: warning: The called method `find_asset' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:635: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:150: warning: The called method `encrypt_and_sign' is defined here
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:175: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
10:08:17 web.1       | /home/enzo/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/messages/metadata.rb:17: warning: The called method `wrap' is defined here
```

this is the network tab in chrome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sg2JR.png)

Comment: You need to do some basic trouble shooting steps here like checking the logs and what the actual raw response sent from your rails server is.

Comment: already updated

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong from the logs. Please check the actual raw response by using postman, cURL or looking at the network tab in the web inspector.

Comment: I forgot to write that I installed bootstrap with yarn, and since that I started to have that problem but I don't see any error thrown by rails

Comment: You need to click the first line in the web inspector (`sign_in`) and check the response tab. That shows you exactly what rails sent to the browser. You can also run `$ curl localhost:3000`

Comment: I clicked in sign_in and showed me a lot of stuff that I don't know what they are (never did that before) but when ran $ curl localhost:5000 (foreman starts at port 5000) this was the output <html><body>You are being <a href="http://localhost:5000/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

Answer (score 1):

After a hard debbuging I finally have found that the yield tag was the problem, now my app is working again haha